# Google Colab: What does a spinning play button with broken line mean?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Recently, I have seen the play button (the one to execute the cell) will have a spinning state with broken line as border and staying like this for a long time. But eventually, the line will turn solid and the thing will execute relatively fast after that. I would like to understand what the "broken" boundary mean? It seems to me it just hangs there waiting for something before actually running any code.

See image attach on that play button.[image]

Comment: I think a pattern i noticed is this happens more likely if a large pandas dataframe is being accessed first time after a read_feather(...) to obtain it. I am not sure if this is 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

The spinning dashed line means the execution of the cell is queued behind an earlier execution.

(If you haven't yet executed a cell, it's likely that the backend is blocked by attempting to generate a completion or objection inspection. These should finish within a few seconds.)

Comment: While this may be correct in general, I suspect "... queued behind an earlier execution" may not be the right description for my case. Whenever I ran into this, there's no pending result from any prior run. Your "backend is blocked by attempting to generate ... object inspection" may be closer to whats happening. I now see this pattern whenever the obj is big in memory, even if the execution "should be" fast (such as len(...)).